# python: handle out of range numpy indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am using the following code to rotate an image along it's y-axis.

```
y, x = np.indices(im1.shape[:2])
return im1[y, ((x-im1.shape[1]/2)/math.cos(t*math.pi/2)+im1.shape[1]/2).astype(np.int)]
```

Some of the values are intentionally out-of-range.  I would like for out of range pixels to be black (0, 0, 0).  How can I allow the in range indices to work, while replacing the out-of range with black?

Comment: I see two possible ways: conditional statements, or ternary operator. I'd rather use conditional.

Comment: Could use a try / except IndexError block and set the black values when the index error is caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mask them:

```
# transform
>>> x2 = ((x-im1.shape[1]/2)/np.cos(t*np.pi/2)+im1.shape[1]/2).astype(np.int)
# check bounds
>>> allowed = np.where((x2>=0) & (x2<im1.shape[1]))
# preallocate with zeros
>>> res = np.zeros_like(im1)
# fill in within-bounds pixels
>>> res[allowed] = im1[y[allowed],x2[allowed]]
>>> 
# one possible economy I left out for clarity
>>> np.all(y[allowed] == allowed[0])
True
```